# Mdi sub window close

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, mdichild

I would like to close the `MDI subwindow` with a push of a button within the window instead of closing it with the `x` at the top. I have another file with a few classes that has all of the information about the window that is opening up in the MDI area. I have tried `self.close()` but that leaves the window open and clears all of the widgets from the window. I will post the code below for how I am adding the subwindow to the MDI area.

```
subWindow = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow()
New_Window = NewMDIWindow()
subWindow.setWidget(New_Window)
subWindow.setObjectName("New_Window")
subWindow.setWindowTitle("New SubWindow")
self.MainUi.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subWindow )

subWindow.show()
```

Comment: what is `MainUi` and `self`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The X button closes the QMdiSubWindow, not the widget inscribed on it, so the button should close the subwindow:

```
your_QPushButton.clicked.connect(your_QMdiSubWindow.close)
```

Complete Example:

```
class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget))

        self.mdiArea = QtWidgets.QMdiArea(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.layout().addWidget(self.mdiArea)

        subWindow = QtWidgets.QMdiSubWindow(self)

        widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout())
        btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton("close", widget) 
        widget.layout().addWidget(btn)

        btn.clicked.connect(subWindow.close)

        subWindow.setWidget(widget)
        subWindow.setObjectName("New_Window")
        subWindow.setWindowTitle("New SubWindow")
        self.mdiArea.addSubWindow(subWindow)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! That seemed to do the trick!! Any idea why it is now saying "QWaitCondition: Destroyed while threads are still waiting" when I close the main window?

Comment: If the code is like the one I show you should not have that problem, but give me information I can not tell you anymore.

Comment: In most of the cases, the subwindow close button is not in the main window.

Comment: @Kumar Hmm, okay, but what does that have to do with the question in the post?